# Excel sharing with multiple users without getting locked

Tags: excel

I've an excel sheet in the OneDrive. The problem is it doesnt allow to edit in excel if someones already using the online feature.
This may sounds dumb but is there any work around to make this possible other than saving it to another location and re uploding to the onedrive?
The problem is some excel sheets contain more than 15, 000 rows and its really laggy when we try to edit in browser. Also advanced sorting methods arent in there. So were entering to the edit in excel mode and opens in read only mode or saving to local folder and re-upload.

Answer (score 1):

check this... https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104

Why am I getting the "File is locked" error?

There are a handful of reasons why this error can occur. The most common one is because someone has opened the file with a version of Excel that doesn't support co-authoring. If just one person does this, then everyone else will get the "locked" error — even if everyone else is using a version of Excel that does support co-authoring.

Versions of Excel that support co-authoring:

Excel 2016 for Windows*

Excel 2016 for Mac*

Excel Online

Excel for Android

Excel for iOS

Excel Mobile

- Co-authoring in this version requires the latest version of Excel installed, and requires you to sign in to Office with an Office 365 subscription account. Please note that if you have a work or school account, you might not have a version of Office that supports co-authoring yet. This might be because your administrator hasn’t provided the latest version to install. Or, if you're using Excel 2016 for Windows, it might be because your company or school is on the Semi-Annual Update Channel. You can tell if you are on this channel by going to File > Account. If it says Semi-annual Channel next to About Excel, then co-authoring isn’t available yet for you.

If you are still getting the "locked" error, see Excel file is locked out for editing for more solutions to this problem.